# Facebook API to do sentimental analysis

Tags: android, facebook, sentiment-analysis

I am developing an android native application for sentimental analysis. The context is I need to get the information from the social media like Twitter and Facebook. I have done it for Twitter by using the API to get the 100 latest tweets about the particular organisation. That is fine.

Now I am trying to do the same for Facebook. Is there any free API available for this sentimental analysis.

Comment: Does this help? http://blog.datumbox.com/how-to-build-your-own-facebook-sentiment-analysis-tool/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming to get the Twitter analysis working you used their 'firehose.'

If that is the case, and you're looking for a Facebook equivalent: it doesn't exist. Perhaps it's because the dynamics of these two social networks are not exactly identical and so what each is trying to achieve is different.

While some Facebook users' activities can be completely public (as per their choosing), most of the content is behind walls, so to speak. So unless you scrape the public info and do some analysis on it, as of right now there is no API support for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it for a particular organization they probably have a facebook page.  Since almost all pages are public you can use the Facebook API to to query that page and get all the comments from that page. Once you have those comments you can perform sentiment analysis on them.  The query might look something like:

```
$facebook->api("pageName/posts?fields=created_time,id,message,story,type,picture,shares,likes,comments.limit(5000)");
```

The above example is in php but you can find an equivalent Java example.
Since there is no stream like functionality for Facebook you would have to set, maybe a cron job, to run it every hour to get the latest comments.